# Estou perdendo o state com ao retornar página com <Link> do react-router-dom - REACT

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Estou criando uma aplicação em React utilizando a api do github, ela lista os repositórios de um determinado usuário, cada item (cada repositório listado) tem um Link do react-router-dom chamado "Detalhes", o link redireciona para outra página da minha aplicação onde tem os detalhes do repositório, estou usando rotas para isso.

Na página "detalhes" tenho um outro Link com react-router-dom direcionando para a página inicial, o problema é que quando volto para a página inicial ele limpa o state, tem alguma maneira de voltar a página sem fazer esse "reset" dos estados?

Vi em alguns lugares que ele não deveria "resetar" os estados, pois o link com o routes não dá reload na página, então acho que possa ser algum erro na minha lógica.

A minha primeira solução foi utilizar localStorage no lugar de state, mas isso não me parece a melhor solução.

Segue a minha index.js onde listo todos os repositórios:

```
state = {
    repos: [],
    avatar_url:'',
    totalRepos:0,
    totalPages:0,
    page:1
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setUserGithub();
    this.loadRepos();
    this.loadReposPagination();
}

setUserGithub(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('userGitHub')){
        localStorage.setItem('userGitHub', 'gpontes98');
    }
}

loadRepos = async () =>{
    const response = await apiGitHub.get(`/${localStorage.getItem('userGitHub')}/repos`);
    const avatar_url = response.data[0].owner.avatar_url;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(response.data.length / this.reposPerPage);
    this.setState({totalRepos:response.data.length ,avatar_url, totalPages});
}

loadReposPagination = async(page = 1) =>{
    const response = await apiGitHub.get(`/${localStorage.getItem('userGitHub')}/repos?per_page=${this.reposPerPage}&page=${page}`);
    this.setState({repos:response.data, page});
}

prevPage = () =>{
    const { page } = this.state;
    if(page === 1) return;
    this.loadReposPagination(page-1);
}

nextPage = () =>{
    const { page, totalPages } = this.state;
    if(page >= totalPages) return;
    this.loadReposPagination(page+1);
}
```

A página detalhes:

```
    state = {
    Repo: []
}

async componentDidMount(){
    const { userGitHub, id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await apiGitHub.get(`/${userGitHub}/repos`);
    
    for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        if(response.data[i].id === parseInt(id)){
            this.setState({Repo:response.data[i]});
            break;
        }
    }
}

render(){
    const { Repo } = this.state;
    return(
        <div className="repo-details">
            <h1>{Repo.full_name}</h1>
            <p>{Repo.description}</p>

            <a href={Repo.html_url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Acessar no GitHub</a>

            <Link to={'/'}> Voltar </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

E a routes.js

```
const Routes = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
        <Route path="/repos/:userGitHub/:id" component={Repo}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

Se estiver fazendo algo muito estranho peço que me avisem, estou começando agora com react e é tudo muito novo para mim ainda.

Obrigado,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Switch nas suas routes essa solução será adequada para você:

A navegação com Switch no react-router-dom "desmonta" seu componente ao mudar de rota, com uma exceção: rotas aninhadas

Se você for de "rotaum/" para "rotadois/" seu componente renderizado em "rotaum/" será desmontado portanto seus states deixarão de existir, quando acessar novamente a "rotaum/" seu componente será criado e renderizado do zero.

Se você for de "rotaum/" para "rotaum/rotadois" o componente da "rotaum/" não será desmontado e portanto seus states continuarão a existir e quando você voltar para esse componente estará como você deixou.

Fonte:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6804